# Comparing Bayesian hierarchical models with different sample sizes

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, bic, waic, dic

I have observation data covering a certain period of time. I follow a block-maxima approach where the data are segmented into equal time intervals .My goal is to first develop a Bayesian Hierarchical model. Secondly, running the same model structure for different time intervals.

For my type of data and the type of relationship used, I am using DIC and WAIC for model comparison. Basically, I want to find out what is the optimum time interval to use using DIC and/or WAIC.

The problem is that for the same observation period, different time intervals will yield different sample sizes. Segmenting the data into smaller time intervals will result in more records.

The calculation for WAIC includes two terms.
WAIC = -2* first_term + 2* second_term
first_term is the sum of log averaged likelihood over n samples.
Second term is the summation of variance of log likelihood over n samples

**Question1:**
Is simply dividing the WAIC over n sample size considered a valid adjustment to calculate WAIC_adjusted, so that I can use WAIC_adjusted to compare the models with different sample sizes?

**Question2:**
Does using DIC require any adjustments for the difference in sample sizes across different models? or is it ok because we are using the mean of posterior deviance and not the sum?

Thanks